# Making a copy of the DOM

Tags: javascript

If I am going to change the `document`, can I make a copy of the old version by something like `oldDoc =` (copy of document, by value) and then use things like `oldDoc.getElementById('myElement').innerHTML`?

Comment: Thanks guys, I was just looking for a quick and dirty way, I'm sure it stores a lot of unnecessary stuff besides the `innerHTML` that I wanted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using the function `cloneNode` like this:

```
var oldDoc = document.cloneNode(true);
```

You can read more about this function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).
Also, here is a snippet with a small working example:

```js
const docCopy = document.cloneNode(true);
document.querySelector('div').textContent = 'New div content';

console.log(docCopy.querySelector('div').textContent);
console.log(document.querySelector('div').textContent);
```

```html
<div>Old div content</div>
```