# Making a copy of the DOM in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61570100/803990) we learned how to use `cloneNode` to make a copy of the `document` in JavaScript. Does it make sense to do something similar in jQuery? That is, something like

```
old$ = $.cloneNode(true);


if (old$('#myId').html() == 'Hello, world!') {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jquery's clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function to clone the body.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var _clone = $("body").clone();
  console.log(_clone.find("div").html());
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>https://api.jquery.com/clone/</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great! One gotcha I ran into was that `$old('#myId').html()` doesn't work, but `$old.find('#myId').html()` does.